# fetch rate for fetching data from wikipedia webservice

Tags: json, web-services, wikipedia-api

I need to fetch around 10'000 texts from wikipedia for analysing purpose.

Actually I pause the fetching process for 3 seconds between the fetches to not burden the wikipedia service. I fear otherwise my ip will be restricted.

Is there any regulation how many wikipedia webapi request can be done in a specific timeslot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [API etiquette](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette), nothing specific though. Three seconds between requests should be plenty. Make sure to use a proper user-agent with a contact address though.